# Bootstrap mobile navigation not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

my bootstrap navigation works fine on desktop but as it goes to mobile it won't open the content.

http://designmonstr.ejectcorelabs.co.uk/1.5.5/en/

i have made a plus icon which i want to open the content but for some reason it doesn't work?

any help? i have tried multiple things but still can't seem to get it to work

as the drop down a is a link i needed to add a + so thats clickable in mobile to open the rest of the links under that category

Answer (score 0):

Did you rename any of the classes or ids, it appears that your javascript is not acting on `open`.  Double check to make sure that the script looking at the correct class for open.  If you want to post the css, js, and specific html you have been messing with that would be helpful.